# UK visit visa refusal today

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am quite confused. I have just been refused a visit UK visa for not showing ties to my home country.

Please see attached. I just want to add that:
- I have lived in the UK since January 2012, and I have exited and re-entered the UK several times while being a student. I got my bachelor's degree there and started my master.

However due to medical reasons I have stopped my master's and my Tier 4 visa has been curtailed.

- I should have included my previous passport as it has the majority of my stamps in and out of the country (UK) with my first ever student visa before my resident permit was issued.
- I also submitted a return ticket from the UK to morocco on the date of end of my visit.
- The visa was curtailed I arrived in the UK this Thursday and submitted my application on Friday. I literally got back from the UK to apply for a visit visa to visit my fiancée for a while.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi and welcome! This could be a tough sell. You withdrew from your course for medical reasons, flew home just before the deadline, and then immediately, literally the next day, applied for a visitor visa. They're looking for reasons why you have ties that would compel you to return home to Morocco, and it's hard to show any such ties when you didn't even spend a full day at home before applying to come back to the UK. It might unfortunately be necessary to wait until September when you plan to return as a student.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ZachLipton , i just need to visit my fiancee for like a week to see her show as she is an acting student .. that would be in mid June. do you think its possible to reapply again including birth certificate and residential status with my employment certificate and my previous passport which got all the stamps .. ?thank you again

Comment: You are not going to the UK on a visitors visa anytime soon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You left the UK, and immediately applied for a visitor's visa to return to visit your long term partner. With nothing apparently tying  you to Morocco the ECO has concluded, rightly in my opinion, that your intent is to remain in the UK.

You could apply again, including the documents you suggest, and hope for a more accommodating ECO. It's not likely to happen, and you will give the impression that you're desperate. If you are refused again it is likely to impact adversely any future application for a visa, including the one you will need in September to resume your studies.

We can't say what the outcome of a new application will be, but it doesn't look optimistic. Better to concentrate on the more important study visa later in the year and accept that you will miss your fiancée's performance in June.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange! That's a great first answer.

Comment: thank you for your time, will try to reapply on june just for the performance 2 days with booked flights and documents for ties to morroco, i just need those two days instead of the first 19 days i applied to.